# Can I marry a Hindu?

Tags: nikah

I am a Muslim and the girl I want to marry is a non muslim. She is a Hindu. Can I do nikah with her. If yes , does a person from her family needs to be there during nikah.

Answer (score 0):

It is not permissible to marry a Hindu, and the evidence for that would be:

Allah (SWT) says:

> “Do not marry idolatresses (al mushrikāt) till they believe; and certainly a believing maid is better than an idolatress even though she would please you; and do not marry idolaters (al Mushrikīn) till they believe (hata yūminū), and certainly a believing slave is better than an idolater, even though he would please you. These invite to the Fire, and Allah invites to the Garden and to forgiveness by His grace, and makes clear His revelations to mankind so that they may remember.”
>
> Qur’an 2:221.

Allah (SWT) forbids us from marrying idolatresses or people who worship someone with Allah (SWT). Hope this helps In Sha Allah
Thanks,